# Getting different timezone IE11 and Chrome browser for jsTimezoneDetect js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone

Getting different output for both browser if we select '(UTC +01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris' in system.

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
var tzName = tz.name();
```

Output:

IE11: Europe/Berlin
Chrome: Europe/Paris

Comment: jsTimezoneDetect uses the `Intl` api if available (-> [line 408ff.](https://github.com/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/blob/master/jstz.main.js#L408)) otherwise it uses its own "database" of names. `Europe/Berlin` is from the internal "database", `Europe/Paris` from `Intl`. IE11 doesn't support [`Intl.DateTimeFormat.resolvedOptions().timeZone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions#browserkompatibilit%C3%A4t)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any alternative for this?

Comment: I would get rid of IE11 (or tell `.determine()` to not use `Intl`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://github.com/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/blob/master/README.md#limitations) docs:

> **Limitations**
> This script does not do geo-location, nor does it care very much about historical time zones. So if you are unhappy with the time zone "Europe/Berlin" when the user is in fact in "Europe/Stockholm" - this script is not for you. They are both identical in modern time.

Indeed, if we carefully examine and compare the history of time zone changes for [Berlin](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?syear=1970&eyear=2030) and [Paris](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/paris?syear=1970&eyear=2030), we find that they have been identical since 1980.  Thus, unless your application is dealing with dates before 1980, it is inconsequential whether you detect `Europe/Berlin` or `Europe/Paris`.

As to which is more correct, the CLDR `windowsZones.xml` file (which is the canonical mapping between Windows and IANA time zones) [contains the following](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/aed88e021847ea2ec2f792eafd3c30effb8c89d0/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml#L339-L340):

```xml
<!-- (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris -->
<mapZone other="Romance Standard Time" territory="001" type="Europe/Paris"/>
```

Chrome uses the `Intl` API, which internally uses ICU, which contains the CLDR data.  Thus, Chrome is providing the more correct answer.  You should get the same answer in FireFox, Edge, and other modern web browsers.

Internet Explorer is older and doesn't contain the data needed to resolve this correctly.  Thus, libraries like jsTimeZoneDetect (and also moment-timezone via `moment.tz.guess()`) first try to use the `Intl` approach, but when not available they make an educated guess by testing various known points in time for their UTC offset changes.  Since it's just a guess, it's sometimes going to be imprecise.

If you are interested, there's a community-maintained [compatibility chart](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/) that tracks which browsers support the "correct" time zone detection process.  Expand the "DateTimeFormat" section and check the row labeled *"resolvedOptions().timeZone defaults to the host environment"*

[image]

Comment: You might also be interested in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge